# How to custom a toolbar in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a problem with my CKEDITOR. I try to customise the toolbar to have juste the button I want but when I try to put a toolbar in the code I have no toobar in ckeditor on my web app. I mean my ckeditor is created but I don't have the toolbar.

this is my javascript code:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'professionnal_mailtemplate_response_template', {
     toolbar: [

         { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat', 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
         { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
         { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
         { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link' ] }
     ]
 } );

 CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '/../js/ckfinder/' )
```

Someone can help me please ? Because I search but for now I didn't find what is wrong.

Thank in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe, with this configuration you need to use **toolbarGroups** property, not **toolbar**:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'professionnal_mailtemplate_response_template', {
     toolbarGroups: [
         { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat', 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
         { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
         { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
         { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link' ] }
     ]
 } );
```

Comment: Thank for your help !!! I put this in my code and now I have a toolbar in my ckeditor. Unfortunately I have all button in this toolbar and not the only button I want.

Comment: Looks like, i confused you and myself. For toolbarGroups you can't use **items**, and for toolbar can't use **groups** keys. You can try make your configuration here - http://nightly.ckeditor.com/18-01-19-07-05/full/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html#basic

Comment: I see !! I remove "items" and keep "groups" and name (I also try  just "groups") but it doesn't work.
`var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'professionnal_mailtemplate_response_template',  {
         toolbarGroups: [
             { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ]},
             { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
             { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
             { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] }
         ]
     });`